# How to integrate in-app purchases in Expo applications?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase

I have a question related to in-app purchases with Expo Go.

I'm looking to integrate payments into my mobile app to allow users to unlock premium content.

I noticed that there are no libraries compatible with Expo Go, so I started exploring payments with Stripe, which clearly simplifies the process of using features like Apple Pay and Google Pay.

However, as I understand it, Apple requires developers not to use other payment platforms to handle in-app purchases. Here's an excerpt from the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase):

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase:
> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app (for example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), **you must use in-app purchase**.

The problem is that I am dependent on Expo Go because I use a lot of Expo libraries and notifications, and I don't have a Mac, so it's not possible for me to emulate an iPhone or access XCode.

Is there a way to integrate payments into Expo apps without ejecting the project to native code? Is it certain that we can't use platforms like Stripe for in-app purchases?

Comment: Stripe doesn't support Apple App Store in-app purchases, unfortunately.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.